# Calling up a cat

Tags: single-word-requests

In Russian when we want to call up a cat we say *ks-ks-ks*. What is the usual way to call it up in English?

Comment: Are you trying to find out whether your cat speaks English? Or did you buy a British or American cat that won't come when it's called in Russian? My advice is, forget language altogether. Just open a can of cat food. Your cat will come.

Comment: You are right, I've got a British cat and I want to speak to it in its language :) But I'm really interested in how  you call up cats.

Comment: I usually call a cat by its name. I know what you are going to ask: and if you didn't give a name to the cat?

Comment: I think you are wasting your time. The cat will come as soon as it pleases, and not before.

Comment: @Brian Hooper, let me assure you that you are wrong.

Comment: I used to call for the cat many ways:
Mis mis (danish and dutch).
Puss or Ps ps ps.
or Mis puss, or muss piss (re German and English).
or ks ks ks from the Swedish kiss-kiss-kiss.
or a very high pitched quiet s, like a whistling through the teeth.
The other clicking noises, described above, I would also do.
The best long distance call is done (after a small amount of training) by tapping with a knife or an opener on a can (at something like meal time) - My cat was gone for a couple of hours after I arrived at a new place, but also after that kind of training, but when I tapped the can, it soon

Comment: EdwinRoss; I have to side with @Brian Hooper on this. You have not met a certain cat of my acquaintance. (Although sometimes she'll make only a half hearted effort to run when she really wants to come in but doesn't want it to in any way appear that she's responding to your instructions.) And I must also agree with Robusto. You don't even need to WANT the cat to come. I recall opening a can of salmon for my lunch and hearing a large BANG on the flyscreen door, only to find a cat sitting outside with an innocent expression on her face. John West is the universal feline language.

Comment: Tongue clicks work for many American cats. The sound is sort of like that of an angry squirrel.

Comment: In English, you just "call" the cat, if you "call up" the cat, you are speaking to it on the telephone (or summoning it like a spirit).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A high-pitched *here kitty-kitty* is very common.

Comment: There’s another way that’s fairly common (at least in parts of the UK): a sound made by sucking in air through pursed lips.  I don’t know of any common name for it, though, or way to transcribe it in writing.  I’ve also heard it used, more rarely, to attract small birds (in the wild).

Comment: Thank you Callithumpian and PLL, it is really interesting.

Comment: @PLL Is it a kind of whistling sound? (As a somewhat random point of reference, when I learn to whistle as child (as in "whistle a tune"), I first learned to do so by sucking in air as opposed to blowing it out.)  But it is very easy to produce bird-like sounds this way.

Comment: "Here kitty, kitty" is the one I know.

Comment: The "here" is of longer duration, while each "kitty" is shorter. There "here" is about the duration of a half note and each syllable of both "kitty" utterances is about an eighth note. The interval is a minor third down from "here" to "kit". If you're so inclined, please do an internet search for "prosody minor third."

Answer (score 6):

(reprise...) I know at least one person who attracts his cat by making the sound we generally write as *tsk-tsk* or *tut-tut*. That's the clicking sound made by pressing tip of tongue to roof of mouth, then releasing it sharply to draw air inwards (again, with throat closed). Drifting slightly off-topic, I've long been fascinated by the corresponding "non-vocalised" sound made using the **side** of the tongue, which has particularly strong associations with horses (i.e. - it means "giddy-up, horse!")

Comment: Thank you, I did not even think there could be so many variants of calling up a cat. I will try them all ^..^____?

Comment: Horse, lateral click; cat, palatal click; girlfriend, something like a bilabial click. (Mwah!)

Comment: I think this is called a dental click: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_clicks

Answer (score 4):

*Puss-puss* (or other variations, e.g. *here puss*, etc) is also common in some parts.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst it's not uncommon, I think *here kitty kitty* is a bit twee & self-concious. The most common sound I hear people making is a sort of "squeak" produced by placing the bottom lip loosely against top teeth and drawing air *inwards* across the gap by moving the tongue backwards (with throat closed). I know at least a couple of people who call this non-vocalised sound a "tweet".

Answer (score 2):

In keeping with @Robusto's comment on opening a can of cat food, the most reliable way to get our recalcitrant kitteh to return to the house is to say the cat's name (or a familiar diminutive thereof), followed with "cheese!" in a high-pitched voice.  Kitties seem to love high-pitched voices mentioning food.  The "cheese" vocalization is in fact an offer of food -- sometimes literally a tiny piece of cheese, sometimes actual "cat food".  Imagine a trained dolphin receiving a fish after performing a trick, and you will have imagined a situation which is not completely unlike this one. 
This trick also works for our other cat who was not brought up with cheese as either an offer or a reward.   I think it's the high-pitched voice, with the likely reward of food that does it.

Answer (score 1):

Around our house we holler "Supper Time!" or "Kitty Bribes!" in a high pitched voice.  The high pitch seems to be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> In Russian when we want to call up a cat we say ks-ks-ks.

The sound I've always heard and used (In Scotland, but coming from a North of England family) is **ch-ch-ch-ch**. where the 'ch' is the slightly explosive sound that you get at the start of 'chase' of 'chat'. Or I might also describe the sound as **tch-tch-tch-tch**, where the 'tch' is the same as the sound at the start of [**teuchter**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teuchter).